# Joomla database query returns old value after update

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, civicrm

I'm implementing a basic listener (a [civicrm_post](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC41/CiviCRM+hook+specification#CiviCRMhookspecification-hookcivicrmpost) hook) that's triggered after a DB row is updated/added. 
The problem I'm having is that even though a row in the table has been changed, loading the same row via the Joomla database object returns the previous value.

Let's say I'm changing the name of an object from 'foo' to 'bar'.

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT ...");
```

returns 'foo' as the name, whereas

```
$c = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
mysql_select_db("db", $c);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
```

returns 'bar'.

Is there any caching going on and is there any way I could purge it?

For reference:

- Joomla 2.5.6
- PHP 5.3.10
- MySQL 5.1.36

Edit: Here is a topic I started on the CiviCRM forums that provides more specifics: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,25200.0.html

Edit 2: The "latest developments" and some clarification.

I'm using the hook to push out an updated iCal feed, which is a feed provided by a frontend component of CiviCRM. It doesn't get updated when the hook triggers, even though the database is updated at that point and there is no caching on either end. Apparently CiviCRM uses its own database connector, so the above wording is not strictly valid anymore. Using a hook that triggers a little later (civicrm_postProcess) solved the issue, but it's a "hacky" fix.

Comment: It will not be caching that is the problem. In fact I am very sure you must be querying two different database, tables or records. I am very sure it is not a Joomla issue.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there are three options:

1. @SørenBeckJensen is probably right! try to run:
   `select DATABASE() from dual` 
   and see which DB is being called by each.
2. Another option is that `autocommit` is turned off, in which case you need to commit:
   `$db->setQuery("COMMIT");`
3. The 3rd option is that the `INSERT` is not written correctly (on the first case) and that it fails. But I need to see the query in order to be sure.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a link to the CiviCRM community forums, where I started a thread about this issue. The problem probably lays in another area of the code, especially as CiviCRM apparently uses its own DB wrapper. As for the points you made, the queries are correct and are targeting the correct DB.

Comment: (a) are you sure there is no race-condition ? and (b) did you try to `commit` before you call the `select` ? I would print to log the time that each action is preformed just to make sure that the hook is really called after the update.

Comment: The hooks are triggering correctly. The thing is, if I call CRM_Event_Page_ICalendar directly (the thing that creates the iCal feed), the result is as it should be, whereas calling the same feed via the provided URL produces a feed with old values. I have no actual control over the queries, as I don't want to alter the base code (the whole purpose of this is to move away from a hard-to-maintain custom component that a pervious dev set up).

Comment: @Celos if you cannot add printings to log I'm afraid it'll be very challenging to find the root of the problem...